# How do you breed an Emerald Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

In reading the wiki for trying to get rainbow dragons I am seeing people talk about an emerald dragon. I can not however find any other information on this dragon. Is it real and if so what are it's elements and breeding times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Dragon):

> The Emerald Dragon can be bred by selecting a Crystal Dragon to mate with a Lichen Dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

This wouldn't be the first time they've made a dragon only breedable by a single pairing (the Sakura dragon used to be), so I'd stick with that combo until more pairings are confirmed.

Interestingly, Emerald Dragons can't be bred with eachother:

> The Emerald Dragon cannot be bred with any other dragon, including breeding with another Emerald Dragon.

Comment: Wow, I could not find that page on the wiki this morning when I tried. Thanks!

Comment: @James it's only existed for less than a day

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is real, and I got mine by breeding a Crystal and a Lichen. Dont use a Lichen, then a Crystal, other wise, u will never get it. For me, I got mine on the 3rd try, so I think is is easy. Also, if u use the epic breeding island, it gives u a 25% better chance of u getting one.  (Sry bout the u's, I m using my phone)

Comment: Multiple tries with no luck. And where is that 25% chance coming from? at that rate I think I should have 5 by now :D